# Why aren’t all the references appearing in the bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have an issue with the generation of the bibliography. Only the first 46 references are displayed after the execution of the code while the remaining references do not appear after the compilation. Here is my LaTeX source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[french, british]{babel}
\newcommand\sbullet[1][.5]{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#1}{$\bullet$}}}}}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[acronym,nomain,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{thmtools}       
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
Universit\'{e} Cadi Ayyad \hfill 03 Septembre 2021 

Facult\'{e} des Sciences Juridiques, \'{E}conomiques

et Sociales

D\'{e}partement des Sciences \'{E}conomiques
\end{flushleft}

\begin{center}
  Travail à Faire
\end{center}

\begin{flushleft}
Effectu\'{e}e par:  \hfill Examin\'{e}e par: 
\end{flushleft}

\vspace{0.0005cm}

\hrule

\vspace{0.0005cm}

\title{Un Modèle Bayésien à Changement de Régime Markovien de Volatilité des Rendements Boursiers: Cas du MASI}
\date{}
\author{}
\let\newpage\relax%
\maketitle


\begin{otherlanguage}{french}
\bibliographystyle{} 
\thispagestyle{empty}
\bibliography{}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Nelson, D.B. (1996). “Modelling Stock Market Volatility Changes,” }\\
\text{in P. Rossi (ed), Modelling Stock Market Volatility, Academic Press, 3-15.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Mandelbrot, Benoit.  (1963).  ‘The variation of certain speculative prices’.}\\
\text{Journal of Business.  Vol. 36, pp 394-419.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Fama, E.F. (1965). “The behaviour of stock market prices,” }\\
\text{Journal of Business, 38, 34-105. \texttt{doi:10.1086/294743},}\\
\text{\texttt{http://dx.doi.org/10.1086/294743}}

\bibitem{} 
\text{French, K.R. and Roll, R. (1986). “Stock Return Variance: }\\
\text{The Arrival of Information and the Reaction of Traders,”  \texttt{doi:10.1016/}}\\
\text{\texttt{0304-405X(86)90004-8}, \texttt{http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0304-405X(86)}}\\
\text{90004-8 Journal of Financial Economics, 17, 5-26.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Schwert, G.W. (1988). “Business Cycles, Financial Crises and }\\
\text{University of Rochester, William E. Simon Graduate School }\\
\text{Stock Volatility,” Mimeo. of Business, Rochester, NY.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Officer, R.R. (1973). “The Variability of the Market }\\
\text{Exchange,” Journal of Business, 46, 434-453. \texttt{doi:10.1086/295551}, \texttt{http://dx.doi}}\\
\texttt{.org/10.1086/295551}\\
\text{}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Fama, E.F., and Schwert, G.W. (1977). “Asset returns and 
inflation,” Journal of}\\
\text{Business, 38,  34-105. \texttt{doi:10.1086/294743}, \texttt{http://dx.doi.org/10.1086/294743}}\\
\text{}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Christie, A.A. (1982). “The Stochastic Behaviour of Common 
Stock Variances: Value,}\\
\text{Leverage and Interest Rate Effects,” Journal of Financial Economics, 10, 407-432.}\\
\text{\texttt{doi:10.1016/0304-405X(82)90018-6}, \texttt{http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0304-405X(82)}}\\
\texttt{90018-6}\\
\text{}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Glosten, L.R., Jagannathan, R., and  Runkie, D. (1989). “Relationship Between}\\
\text{the Expected Value and the Volatility of the Nominal Excess Return on Stocks,”}\\
\text{Banking Research Center Working Paper No.166. Northwestern University, Evanston, IL.}\\
\text{}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Bollerslev, T. (1986). Generalized autoregressive conditional heteroscedasticity.}\\
\text{Journal of Economics, 31, 307-327.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Engle, R. F. (1982). Autoregressive Conditional Heteroscedasticity with Estimates}\\
\text{of the Variance of United Kingdom Inflation. Econometrica, 50, 987-1007.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Nobel Media (2003). "The Prize in Economic Sciences 2003 – Press Release.”}\\
\texttt{URL https://www.nobelprize.org/nobel\_prizes/economic-sciences\\/laureates/2003/press.html.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Francq, C. and Zakoian, J.M. (2010) GARCH Models: Structure, Statistical}\\
\text{Inference and Financial Applications. John Wiley \& Sons Ltd., Chichester.}\\
\text{https://doi.org/10.1002/9780470670057}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Masset, Philippe, Volatility Stylized Facts (September 11, 2011). Available at}\\
\text{SSRN: \texttt{https://ssrn.com/abstract=1804070} or \texttt{http://dx.doi.org/10.2}}\\
\texttt{139/ssrn.1804070}


\bibitem{} 
\text{Engle, Robert. 2001. "GARCH 101: The Use of ARCH/GARCH Models in}\\
\text{Applied Econometrics." Journal of Economic Perspectives, 15 (4): 157-168.}\\
\texttt{DOI: 10.1257/jep.15.4.157}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Zi-Yi Guo, Risk management of Bitcoin futures with GARCH models, Finance}\\
\text{Research Letters, 2021, 102197, ISSN 1544-6123, \texttt{https://doi.org/10.1016/j.}}\\
\texttt{frl.2021.102197.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Jong-Min Kim, Dong H. Kim, Hojin Jung, Estimating yield spreads volatility using}\\
\text{GARCH-type models, The North American Journal of Economics and Finance,}\\
\text{Volume 57, 2021, 101396, ISSN 1062-9408, \texttt{https://doi.org/10.1016/j.najef.}}\\
\texttt{2021.101396.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Siaw, Richmond and Ofosu-Hene, Eric and Tee, Evans, Investment Portfolio}\\
\text{Optimization with GARCH Models (April 28, 2017). Elk Asia Pacific Journal of}\\
\text{Finance and Risk Management, Volume 8, Issue 2 (2017), Available at SSRN:}\\
\texttt{https://ssrn.com/abstract=2987932}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Chou, R.Y. (1998) “Volatility Persistence and Stock Valuation: Some Empirical}\\
\text{Evidence Using GARCH,” Journal of Applied Econometrics, 3(4): 279–294.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Lamoureux, Christopher G., and William D. Lastrapes. “Persistence in Variance,}\\
\text{Structural Change, and the GARCH Model.” Journal of Business \& Economic Statistics,}\\
\text{vol. 8, no. 2, 1990, pp. 225–234. JSTOR, \texttt{www.jstor.org/stable/1391985}.}\\
\text{Accessed 21 Aug. 2021.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{West, K.D., Cho, D. 1995. The Predictive Ability of several Models of Exchange}\\
\text{Rate Volatility. Journal of Econometrics 69:367-391.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Rapach, D.E., Strauss, J.K., Wohar, M.E. 2008. Forecasting Stock Return Volatility}\\
\text{in the Presence of Structural Breaks. Frontiers of Economics and Globalisation}\\ 
\text{3:382-426.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Diebold, F.X. (1986) “Modeling the Persistence of Conditional Variance: A Comment,”}\\
\text{Econometric Reviews, 5(1): 51–56.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Lamoureux, C.G. and Lastrapes, W.D. (1990) “Persistence in Variance, Structural}\\
\text{Change and the GARCH Model,” Journal of Business and Economic Statistics,}\\
\text{8(2):225–234.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{M. Angeles Carnero, Daniel Peña, Esther Ruiz, Persistence and Kurtosis in GARCH}\\
\text{and Stochastic Volatility Models, Journal of Financial Econometrics, Volume 2,}\\
\text{Issue 2, March 2004, Pages 319–342, \texttt{https://doi.org/10.1093/jjfinec/nbh012}}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Schwert, G.W. and Seguin, P.J. (1990) “Heteroskedasticity in Stock Returns,”}\\
\text{Journal of Finance, 45(4): 1129–1155.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Nelson, D.B. (1991) “Conditional Heteroscedasticity in Asset Pricing: A New}\\
\text{Approach,” Econometrica, 59(2): 347–370.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Engle, R.F. and Mustafa, C. (1992) “Implied ARCH Models from Options Prices,”}\\
\text{Journal of Econometrics, 52(1–2): 289–311.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Hamilton, J.D. (1989) “A New Approach to the Economic Analysis of Nonstationary}\\
\text{Time Series and the Business Cycle,” Econometrica, 57(2): 357–384.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Hamilton, J.D. and Susmel, R. (1994) “Autoregressive Conditional Heteroscedasticity}\\
\text{and Changes in Regime,” Journal of Econometrics, 
64(1–2): 307–333.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Cai, J. (1994) “A Markov Model of Unconditional Variance in ARCH,” Journal of}\\
\text{Business and Economic Statistics, 12(3): 309–316.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Gray, S.F. (1996) “Modeling the Conditional Distribution of Interest Rates as A}\\
\text{Regime-switching Process,” Journal of Financial Economics, 42(3): 27–62.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{David Ardia, Keven Bluteau, Kris Boudt, Leopoldo Catania, Forecasting risk with}\\
\text{Markov-switching GARCH models:A large-scale performance study, International Journal}\\
\text{of Forecasting, Volume 34, Issue 4, 2018, Pages 733-747, ISSN 0169-2070, \texttt{https://doi.org}}\\
\texttt{/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2018.05.004.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Boonyakunakorn P., Pastpipatkul P., Sriboonchitta S. (2019) Value at Risk of SET}\\
\text{Returns Based on Bayesian Markov-Switching GARCH Approach. In: Kreinovich V.,}\\
\text{Sriboonchitta S. (eds) Structural Changes and their Econometric Modeling. TES}\\
\text{2019. Studies in Computational Intelligence, vol 808. Springer, Cham.}\\
\texttt{https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-04263-9\_25}

\bibitem{}
\text{Runfang, Y., Jiangze, D., \& Xiaotao, L. (2017). Improved Forecast Ability of Oil}\\
\text{Market Volatility Based on combined Markov Switching and GARCH-class Model.}\\
\text{Procedia Computer Science, 122, 415-422.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Nop Sopipan, Pairote Sattayatham, Bhusana Premanode, et al. 2012. Forecasting}\\
\text{volatility of gold price using markov regime switching and trading strategy. Journal}\\
\text{of Mathematical Finance 2, 01 (2012), 121}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Thomas H Goodwin. 1993. Business-cycle analysis with a Markov-switching model.}\\
\text{Journal of Business \& Economic Statistics 11, 3 (1993), 331–339}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Charles Engel and James D Hamilton. 1990. Long swings in the dollar: Are they in}\\
\text{the data and do markets know it? The American Economic Review (1990), 689–713.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Rene Garcia and Pierre Perron. 1996. An analysis of the real interest rate under}\\
\text{regime shifts. The Review of Economics and Statistics (1996), 111–125}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Stephen F Gray. 1996. Modeling the conditional distribution of}\\
\text{interest rates as a regime-switching process. Journal of Financial}\\
\text{Economics 42, 1 (1996), 27–62}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Lucio Sarno and Giorgio Valente. 2000. The cost of carry model and regime shifts}\\
\text{in stock index futures markets: An empirical investigation. Journal of Futures}\\
\text{Markets: Futures, Options, and Other Derivative Products 20, 7 (2000), 603–624.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Amir H Alizadeh, Nikos K Nomikos, and Panos K Pouliasis. 2008. A Markov regime}\\
\text{switching approach for hedging energy commodities. Journal of Banking \& Finance}\\
{32, 9 (2008), 1970–1983}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Michael Bock and Roland Mestel. 2009. A regime-switching relative value arbi-}\\
\text{trage rule. In Operations research proceedings 2008. Springer, 9–14.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Ying Ma, Leonard MacLean, Kuan Xu, and Yonggan Zhao. 2011. A portfolio}\\
\text{optimization model with regime-switching risk factors for sector exchange traded}\\
\text{funds. Pac J Optim 7, 2 (2011), 281–296.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Timothy D Mount, Yumei Ning, and Xiaobin Cai. 2006. Predicting price spikes}\\
\text{in electricity markets using a regime-switching model with time-varying param-}\\
\text{eters. Energy Economics 28, 1 (2006), 62–80.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Glosten, L., Jagannathan, R., \& Runkle, D. (1993). On the Relation between the}\\
\text{Expected Value and the Volatility of the Nominal Excess Return on Stocks.}\\
\text{The Journal of Finance, 48(5), 1779-1801. \texttt{doi:10.2307/2329067}}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Haas M, Mittnik S, Paolella MS (2004). “A New Approach to Markov-Switching}\\
\text{GARCH Models.” Journal of Financial Econometrics, 2(4), 493–530. \texttt{doi: 10.109}}\\
\texttt{3/jjfinec/nbh020.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Klaassen F (2002). “Improving GARCH Volatility Forecasts with Regime Switching}\\
\text{GARCH.” Empirical Economics, 27(2), 363–394. \texttt{doi:10.1007/s001810100100.}}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Ardia D (2008). Financial Risk Management with Bayesian Estimation of GARCH}\\
\text{Models: Theory and Applications, volume 612 of Lecture Notes in Economics and}\\
\text{Mathematical Systems. Springer-Verlag, Berlin Heidelberg. \texttt{doi:10.1007/978-3-54}}\\
\texttt{0-78657-3.}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Christoffersen, P. (1998). Evaluating Interval Forecasts. International Economic}\\
\text{Review, 39(4), 841-862. \texttt{doi:10.2307/2527341}}

\bibitem{} 
\text{Engle, R., \& Manganelli, S. (2004). CAViaR: Conditional Autoregressive Value at}\\
\text{Risk by Regression Quantiles. Journal of Business \& Economic Statistics, 22(4), 367}\\
\text{-381. Retrieved September 2, 2021, from \texttt{http://www.jstor.org/stable/1392044}}


\end{thebibliography}
\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

What could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

I did follow the instructions provided by @Mico, but unfortunately, I still run into the same problem when executing the LaTeX code in overleaf. Here is the new LaTeX source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[french, british]{babel}
\newcommand\sbullet[1][.5]{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#1}{$\bullet$}}}}}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[acronym,nomain,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{thmtools}       
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
Universit\'{e} Cadi Ayyad \hfill 03 Septembre 2021 

Facult\'{e} des Sciences Juridiques, \'{E}conomiques

et Sociales

D\'{e}partement des Sciences \'{E}conomiques
\end{flushleft}

\begin{center}
  Travail à Faire
\end{center}

\begin{flushleft}
Effectu\'{e}e par:  \hfill Examin\'{e}e par: 
\end{flushleft}

\vspace{0.0005cm}

\hrule

\vspace{0.0005cm}

\title{Un Modèle Bayésien à Changement de Régime Markovien de Volatilité des Rendements Boursiers: Cas du MASI}
\date{}
\author{}
\let\newpage\relax%
\maketitle


\begin{otherlanguage}{french}
\bibliographystyle{} 
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\bibliography{}

\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem{1} 
Nelson, D.B. (1996). “Modelling Stock Market Volatility Changes,” in P. Rossi (ed), Modelling Stock Market Volatility, Academic Press, 3-15.

\bibitem{2} 
Mandelbrot, Benoit.  (1963).  ‘The variation of certain speculative prices’. Journal of Business.  Vol. 36, pp 394-419.

\bibitem{3} 
Fama, E.F. (1965). “The behaviour of stock market prices,” Journal of Business, 38, 34-105. doi:10.1086/294743, http://dx.doi.org/10.1086/294743

\bibitem{4} 
French, K.R. and Roll, R. (1986). “Stock Return Variance:
The Arrival of Information and the Reaction of Traders,”  doi:10.1016/0304-405X(86)90004-8, http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0304-405X(86)90004-8 Journal of Financial Economics, 17, 5-26.

\bibitem{5} 
Schwert, G.W. (1988). “Business Cycles, Financial Crises and\
University of Rochester, William E. Simon Graduate SchoolStock Volatility,” Mimeo. of Business, Rochester, NY.

\bibitem{6} 
Officer, R.R. (1973). “The Variability of the Market Exchange,” Journal of Business, 46, 434-453.doi:10. 1086/ 295551, http://dx.doi.org/ 10.1086/295551

\bibitem{7} 
Fama, E.F., and Schwert, G.W. (1977). “Asset returns and 
inflation,” Journal of Business, 38,  34-105. doi:10.10 86/294743, http://dx.doi.org/ 10.1086/294743

\bibitem{8} 
Christie, A.A. (1982). “The Stochastic Behaviour of Common 
Stock Variances: Value, Leverage and Interest Rate Effects,” Journal of Financial Economics, 10, 407-432. doi:10. 1016/0304- 405X(82) 900 18-6, http:// dx.doi.org/10. 1016/03 04-405 X(82)90018-6

\bibitem{9} 
Glosten, L.R., Jagannathan, R., and  Runkie, D. (1989). “Relationship Between the Expected Value and the Volatility of the Nominal Excess Return on Stocks,” Banking Research Center Working Paper No.166. Northwestern University, Evanston, IL.

\bibitem{10} 
Bollerslev, T. (1986). Generalized autoregressive conditional heteroscedasticity. Journal of Economics, 31, 307-327.

\bibitem{11} 
Engle, R. F. (1982). Autoregressive Conditional Heteroscedasticity with Estimates of the Variance of United Kingdom Inflation. Econometrica, 50, 987-1007.

\bibitem{12} 
Nobel Media (2003). "The Prize in Economic Sciences 2003 – Press Release.” URL https://www .nobelprize.org/nobel \_prizes/economic-sciences /laureates/2003/press.html.

\bibitem{13} 
Francq, C. and Zakoian, J.M. (2010) GARCH Models: Structure, Statistical Inference and Financial Applications. John Wiley \& Sons Ltd., Chichester.
https://doi.org/10.1002/9780470670057

\bibitem{14} 
Masset, Philippe, Volatility Stylized Facts (September 11, 2011). Available at SSRN: https://ssrn.com/ abstract=1804070 or http://dx.doi.org /10.2139/ ssrn.1804070


\bibitem{15} 
Engle, Robert. 2001. "GARCH 101: The Use of ARCH/GARCH Models in Applied Econometrics." Journal of Economic Perspectives, 15 (4): 157-168. DOI: 10.1257/jep.15.4.157

\bibitem{16} 
Zi-Yi Guo, Risk management of Bitcoin futures with GARCH models, Finance Research Letters, 2021, 102197, ISSN 1544-6123, https://doi. org/10.1016 /j.frl.2021. 102197.

\bibitem{17} 
Jong-Min Kim, Dong H. Kim, Hojin Jung, Estimating yield spreads volatility using GARCH-type models, The North American Journal of Economics and Finance, Volume 57, 2021, 101396, ISSN 1062-9408, https://doi. org/10.1016 /j.najef.2021. 101396.

\bibitem{18} 
Siaw, Richmond and Ofosu-Hene, Eric and Tee, Evans, Investment Portfolio Optimization with GARCH Models (April 28, 2017). Elk Asia Pacific Journal of Finance and Risk Management, Volume 8, Issue 2 (2017), Available at SSRN:
https://s srn.com/ abstract=2 987932

\bibitem{19} 
Chou, R.Y. (1998) “Volatility Persistence and Stock Valuation: Some Empirical Evidence Using GARCH,” Journal of Applied Econometrics, 3(4): 279–294.

\bibitem{20} 
Lamoureux, Christopher G., and William D. Lastrapes. “Persistence in Variance, Structural Change, and the GARCH Model.” Journal of Business \& Economic Statistics, vol. 8, no. 2, 1990, pp. 225–234. JSTOR, www.jstor.org/stable/1391985.
Accessed 21 Aug. 2021.

\bibitem{21} 
West, K.D., Cho, D. 1995. The Predictive Ability of several Models of Exchange Rate Volatility. Journal of Econometrics 69:367-391.

\bibitem{22} 
Rapach, D.E., Strauss, J.K., Wohar, M.E. 2008. Forecasting Stock Return Volatility in the Presence of Structural Breaks. Frontiers of Economics and Globalisation 3:382-426.

\bibitem{23} 
Diebold, F.X. (1986) “Modeling the Persistence of Conditional Variance: A Comment,” Econometric Reviews, 5(1): 51–56.

\bibitem{24} 
Lamoureux, C.G. and Lastrapes, W.D. (1990) “Persistence in Variance, Structural Change and the GARCH Model,” Journal of Business and Economic Statistics, 8(2):225–234.

\bibitem{25} 
M. Angeles Carnero, Daniel Peña, Esther Ruiz, Persistence and Kurtosis in GARCH and Stochastic Volatility Models, Journal of Financial Econometrics, Volume 2, Issue 2, March 2004, Pages 319–342, https://doi .org/10. 1093/jjfi nec/nbh012

\bibitem{26} 
Schwert, G.W. and Seguin, P.J. (1990) “Heteroskedasticity in Stock Returns,” Journal of Finance, 45(4): 1129–1155.

\bibitem{27} 
Nelson, D.B. (1991) “Conditional Heteroscedasticity in Asset Pricing: A New Approach,” Econometrica, 59(2): 347–370.

\bibitem{28} 
Engle, R.F. and Mustafa, C. (1992) “Implied ARCH Models from Options Prices,” Journal of Econometrics, 52(1–2): 289–311.

\bibitem{29} 
Hamilton, J.D. (1989) “A New Approach to the Economic Analysis of Nonstationary Time Series and the Business Cycle,” Econometrica, 57(2): 357–384.

\bibitem{30} 
Hamilton, J.D. and Susmel, R. (1994) “Autoregressive Conditional Heteroscedasticity and Changes in Regime,” Journal of Econometrics, 
64(1–2): 307–333.

\bibitem{31} 
Cai, J. (1994) “A Markov Model of Unconditional Variance in ARCH,” Journal of Business and Economic Statistics, 12(3): 309–316.

\bibitem{32} 
Gray, S.F. (1996) “Modeling the Conditional Distribution of Interest Rates as A Regime-switching Process,” Journal of Financial Economics, 42(3): 27–62.

\bibitem{33} 
David Ardia, Keven Bluteau, Kris Boudt, Leopoldo Catania, Forecasting risk with Markov-switching GARCH models:A large-scale performance study, International Journal of Forecasting, Volume 34, Issue 4, 2018, Pages 733-747, ISSN 0169-2070, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2018.05.004.

\bibitem{34} 
Boonyakunakorn P., Pastpipatkul P., Sriboonchitta S. (2019) Value at Risk of SET Returns Based on Bayesian Markov-Switching GARCH Approach. In: Kreinovich V., Sriboonchitta S. (eds) Structural Changes and their Econometric Modeling. TES 2019. Studies in Computational Intelligence, vol 808. Springer, Cham.
https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-04263-9\_25

\bibitem{35}
Runfang, Y., Jiangze, D., \& Xiaotao, L. (2017). Improved Forecast Ability of Oil Market Volatility Based on combined Markov Switching and GARCH-class Model. Procedia Computer Science, 122, 415-422.

\bibitem{36} 
Nop Sopipan, Pairote Sattayatham, Bhusana Premanode, et al. 2012. Forecasting volatility of gold price using markov regime switching and trading strategy. Journal of Mathematical Finance 2, 01 (2012), 121

\bibitem{37} 
Thomas H Goodwin. 1993. Business-cycle analysis with a Markov-switching model. Journal of Business \& Economic Statistics 11, 3 (1993), 331–339

\bibitem{38} 
Charles Engel and James D Hamilton. 1990. Long swings in the dollar: Are they in the data and do markets know it? The American Economic Review (1990), 689–713.

\bibitem{39} 
Rene Garcia and Pierre Perron. 1996. An analysis of the real interest rate under regime shifts. The Review of Economics and Statistics (1996), 111–125

\bibitem{40} 
Stephen F Gray. 1996. Modeling the conditional distribution of interest rates as a regime-switching process. Journal of Financial Economics 42, 1 (1996), 27–62

\bibitem{41} 
Lucio Sarno and Giorgio Valente. 2000. The cost of carry model and regime shifts in stock index futures markets: An empirical investigation. Journal of Futures Markets: Futures, Options, and Other Derivative Products 20, 7 (2000), 603–624.

\bibitem{42} 
Amir H Alizadeh, Nikos K Nomikos, and Panos K Pouliasis. 2008. A Markov regime switching approach for hedging energy commodities. Journal of Banking \& Finance 32, 9 (2008), 1970–1983

\bibitem{43} 
Michael Bock and Roland Mestel. 2009. A regime-switching relative value arbitrage rule. In Operations research proceedings 2008. Springer, 9–14.

\bibitem{44} 
Ying Ma, Leonard MacLean, Kuan Xu, and Yonggan Zhao. 2011. A portfolio optimization model with regime-switching risk factors for sector exchange traded funds. Pac J Optim 7, 2 (2011), 281–296.

\bibitem{45} 
Timothy D Mount, Yumei Ning, and Xiaobin Cai. 2006. Predicting price spikes in electricity markets using a regime-switching model with time-varying parameters. Energy Economics 28, 1 (2006), 62–80.

\bibitem{46} 
Glosten, L., Jagannathan, R., \& Runkle, D. (1993). On the Relation between the Expected Value and the Volatility of the Nominal Excess Return on Stocks. The Journal of Finance, 48(5), 1779-1801. doi:10.2307/2329067

\bibitem{47} 
Haas M, Mittnik S, Paolella MS (2004). “A New Approach to Markov-Switching GARCH Models.” Journal of Financial Econometrics, 2(4), 493 –530. doi: 10. 109 3/ jjfi nec /nbh0 20.

\bibitem{48} 
Klaassen F (2002). “Improving GARCH Volatility Forecasts with Regime Switching GARCH.” Empirical Economics, 27(2), 363–394. doi:10. 1007/s0018 10100100.

\bibitem{49} 
Ardia D (2008). Financial Risk Management with Bayesian Estimation of GARCH Models: Theory and Applications, volume 612 of Lecture Notes in Economics and Mathematical Systems. Springer-Verlag, Berlin Heidelberg. doi:10.1007/978-3-540-78657-3.

\bibitem{50} 
Christoffersen, P. (1998). Evaluating Interval Forecasts. International Economic Review, 39(4), 841-862. doi:10.2307/2527341

\bibitem{51} 
Engle, R., \& Manganelli, S. (2004). CAViaR: Conditional Autoregressive Value at Risk by Regression Quantiles. Journal of Business \& Economic Statistics, 22(4), 367-381. Retrieved September 2, 2021, from http: //www.jstor. org/stable/1392044


\end{thebibliography}
\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Why do you have all these `\text` wrappers and hard line breaks inside the `thebibliography` enviroment? If I remove these wrappers, all 51 entries get typeset.

Comment: Hi @Mico, I think I've seen the \text wrappers and hard line breaks being used inside the \thebibliography somewhere when I first started learning writing in TeX. Thanks to your helpful comment they turned out to be unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three major problems with our code: the completely unnecessary and inappropriate use of `\text` throughout the `thebibliograpy` environment, the equally unnecessary and inappropriate use of `\\` to force line breaks, and the failure to use non-empty (and unique) arguments for the `\bibitem` instructions. Taken together, these problems explain why LaTeX just gave up. Remove these issues, and do please use `\url` rather than `\texttt` to encase url and doi strings.

---

Update:

Here's how I would render the bibliography-related code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[french, british]{babel}
\newcommand\sbullet[1][.5]{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#1}{$\bullet$}}}}}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[acronym,nomain,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{thmtools}       
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begingroup % <-- new
\begin{flushleft}
Universit\'{e} Cadi Ayyad \hfill 03 Septembre 2021 

Facult\'{e} des Sciences Juridiques, \'{E}conomiques

et Sociales

D\'{e}partement des Sciences \'{E}conomiques
\end{flushleft}

\begin{center}
  Travail à Faire
\end{center}

\begin{flushleft}
Effectu\'{e}e par:  \hfill Examin\'{e}e par: 
\end{flushleft}

\vspace{0.0005cm}

\hrule

\vspace{0.0005cm}

\title{Un Modèle Bayésien à Changement de Régime Markovien de Volatilité des Rendements Boursiers: Cas du MASI}
\date{}
\author{}
\let\newpage\relax%
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty} % <-- new
\endgroup
\clearpage

\begin{otherlanguage}{french}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{1} 
Nelson, D.B. (1996). “Modelling Stock Market Volatility Changes,” 
in P. Rossi (ed), Modelling Stock Market Volatility, Academic Press, 3--15.

\bibitem{2} 
Mandelbrot, Benoit.  (1963).  ‘The variation of certain speculative prices’. Journal of Business.  Vol. 36, pp 394--419.

\bibitem{3} 
Fama, E.F. (1965). “The behaviour of stock market prices,” Journal of Business, 38, 34-105. 
\url{doi:10.1086/294743}, \url{http://dx.doi.org/10.1086/294743}

\bibitem{4} 
French, K.R. and Roll, R. (1986). “Stock Return Variance:
The Arrival of Information and the Reaction of Traders,”  
Journal of Financial Economics, 17, 5--26,
\url{doi:10.1016/0304-405X(86)90004-8}, 
\url{http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0304-405X(86)90004-8}.

\bibitem{5} 
Schwert, G.W. (1988). “Business Cycles, Financial Crises and
Stock Volatility,” University of Rochester, William E. Simon Graduate School Mimeo. of Business, Rochester, NY.

\bibitem{6} 
Officer, R.R. (1973). “The Variability of the Market Exchange,” Journal of Business, 46, 434--453.
\url{doi:10. 1086/295551}, 
\url{http://dx.doi.org/ 10.1086/295551}

\bibitem{7} 
Fama, E.F., and Schwert, G.W. (1977). “Asset returns and 
inflation,” Journal of Business, 38,  34--105. 
\url{doi:10.10 86/294743}, \url{http://dx.doi.org/10.1086/294743}

\bibitem{8} 
Christie, A.A. (1982). “The Stochastic Behaviour of Common 
Stock Variances: Value, Leverage and Interest Rate Effects,” 
Journal of Financial Economics, 10, 407--432. 
\url{doi:10.1016/0304-405X(82)900 18-6}, 
\url{http:// dx.doi.org/10.1016/03 04-405 X(82)90018-6}

\bibitem{9} 
Glosten, L.R., Jagannathan, R., and  Runkie, D. (1989). “Relationship Between the Expected Value and the Volatility of the Nominal Excess Return on Stocks,” Banking Research Center Working Paper No.~166. Northwestern University, Evanston, IL.

\bibitem{10} 
Bollerslev, T. (1986). Generalized autoregressive conditional heteroscedasticity. Journal of Economics, 31, 307--327.

\bibitem{11} 
Engle, R. F. (1982). Autoregressive Conditional Heteroscedasticity with Estimates of the Variance of United Kingdom Inflation. Econometrica, 50, 987--1007.

\bibitem{12} 
Nobel Media (2003). "The Prize in Economic Sciences 2003---Press Release.” 
\url{https://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/economic-scienceslaureates/2003/press.html}.

\bibitem{13} 
Francq, C. and Zakoian, J.M. (2010) GARCH Models: Structure, Statistical Inference and Financial Applications. John Wiley \& Sons Ltd., Chichester.
\url{https://doi.org/10.1002/9780470670057}

\bibitem{14} 
Masset, Philippe, Volatility Stylized Facts (September 11, 2011). Available at SSRN.
\url{https://ssrn.com/abstract=1804070} or 
\url{http://dx.doi.org/10.2139/ssrn.1804070}


\bibitem{15} 
Engle, Robert. 2001. "GARCH 101: The Use of ARCH/GARCH Models in Applied Econometrics." Journal of Economic Perspectives, 15 (4): 157--168. 
\url{doi:10.1257/jep.15.4.157}

\bibitem{16} 
Zi-Yi Guo, Risk management of Bitcoin futures with GARCH models, Finance Research Letters, 2021, 102197, ISSN 1544-6123, 
\url{https://doi.org/10.1016/j.frl.2021.102197}.

\bibitem{17} 
Jong-Min Kim, Dong H. Kim, Hojin Jung, Estimating yield spreads volatility using GARCH-type models, The North American Journal of Economics and Finance, Volume 57, 2021, 101396, ISSN 1062-9408, 
\url{https://doi.org/10.1016/j.najef.2021.101396}.

\bibitem{18} 
Siaw, Richmond and Ofosu-Hene, Eric and Tee, Evans, Investment Portfolio Optimization with GARCH Models (April 28, 2017). Elk Asia Pacific Journal of Finance and Risk Management, Volume 8, Issue 2 (2017), Available at SSRN:
\url{https://ssrn.com/abstract=2987932}

\bibitem{19} 
Chou, R.Y. (1998) “Volatility Persistence and Stock Valuation: Some Empirical Evidence Using GARCH,” Journal of Applied Econometrics, 
3(4):279--294.

\bibitem{20} 
Lamoureux, Christopher G., and William D. Lastrapes. “Persistence in Variance, Structural Change, and the GARCH Model.” Journal of Business \& Economic Statistics, vol. 8, no. 2, 1990, pp. 225--234. JSTOR, 
\url{www.jstor.org/stable/1391985}. Accessed 21 Aug. 2021.

\bibitem{21} 
West, K.D., Cho, D. 1995. The Predictive Ability of several Models of Exchange Rate Volatility. Journal of Econometrics 69:367--391.

\bibitem{22} 
Rapach, D.E., Strauss, J.K., Wohar, M.E. 2008. Forecasting Stock Return Volatility in the Presence of Structural Breaks. Frontiers of Economics and Globalisation 3:382--426.

\bibitem{23} 
Diebold, F.X. (1986) “Modeling the Persistence of Conditional Variance: A Comment,” Econometric Reviews, 5(1):51--56.

\bibitem{24} 
Lamoureux, C.G. and Lastrapes, W.D. (1990) “Persistence in Variance, Structural Change and the GARCH Model,” Journal of Business and Economic Statistics, 8(2):225--234.

\bibitem{25} 
M. Angeles Carnero, Daniel Peña, Esther Ruiz, Persistence and Kurtosis in GARCH and Stochastic Volatility Models, Journal of Financial Econometrics, Volume 2, Issue 2, March 2004, Pages 319--342, 
\url{https://doi.org/10.1093/jjfinec/nbh012}

\bibitem{26} 
Schwert, G.W. and Seguin, P.J. (1990) “Heteroskedasticity in Stock Returns,” Journal of Finance, 45(4): 1129--1155.

\bibitem{27} 
Nelson, D.B. (1991) “Conditional Heteroscedasticity in Asset Pricing: A New Approach,” Econometrica, 59(2): 347--370.

\bibitem{28} 
Engle, R.F. and Mustafa, C. (1992) “Implied ARCH Models from Options Prices,” Journal of Econometrics, 52(1--2): 289--311.

\bibitem{29} 
Hamilton, J.D. (1989) “A New Approach to the Economic Analysis of Nonstationary Time Series and the Business Cycle,” Econometrica, 57(2): 357--384.

\bibitem{30} 
Hamilton, J.D. and Susmel, R. (1994) “Autoregressive Conditional Heteroscedasticity and Changes in Regime,” Journal of Econometrics, 
64(1--2): 307--333.

\bibitem{31} 
Cai, J. (1994) “A Markov Model of Unconditional Variance in ARCH,” Journal of Business and Economic Statistics, 12(3):309--316.

\bibitem{32} 
Gray, S.F. (1996) “Modeling the Conditional Distribution of Interest Rates as A Regime-switching Process,” Journal of Financial Economics, 42(3): 27--62.

\bibitem{33} 
David Ardia, Keven Bluteau, Kris Boudt, Leopoldo Catania, Forecasting risk with Markov-switching GARCH models: A large-scale performance study, International Journal of Forecasting, Volume 34, Issue 4, 2018, Pages 733-747, ISSN 0169-2070, 
\url{https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2018.05.004}.

\bibitem{34} 
Boonyakunakorn P., Pastpipatkul P., Sriboonchitta S. (2019) Value at Risk of SET Returns Based on Bayesian Markov-Switching GARCH Approach. In: Kreinovich V., Sriboonchitta S. (eds) Structural Changes and their Econometric Modeling. TES 2019. Studies in Computational Intelligence, vol 808. Springer, Cham.
\url{https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-04263-9_25}

\bibitem{35}
Y. Runfang, D. Jiangze, and L. Xiaotao (2017). Improved Forecast Ability of Oil Market Volatility Based on combined Markov Switching and GARCH-class Model. Procedia Computer Science, 122, 415--422.

\bibitem{36} 
Nop Sopipan, Pairote Sattayatham, Bhusana Premanode, et al. 2012. Forecasting volatility of gold price using markov regime switching and trading strategy. Journal of Mathematical Finance 2, 01 (2012), 121

\bibitem{37} 
Thomas H Goodwin. 1993. Business-cycle analysis with a Markov-switching model. Journal of Business \& Economic Statistics 11, 3 (1993), 331--339

\bibitem{38} 
Charles Engel and James D. Hamilton. 1990. Long swings in the dollar: Are they in the data and do markets know it? The American Economic Review (1990), 689--713.

\bibitem{39} 
Rene Garcia and Pierre Perron. 1996. An analysis of the real interest rate under regime shifts. The Review of Economics and Statistics (1996), 111--125

\bibitem{40} 
Stephen F. Gray. 1996. Modeling the conditional distribution of interest rates as a regime-switching process. Journal of Financial Economics 42, 1 (1996), 27--62

\bibitem{41} 
Lucio Sarno and Giorgio Valente. 2000. The cost of carry model and regime shifts in stock index futures markets: An empirical investigation. Journal of Futures Markets 20, 7 (2000), 603--624.

\bibitem{42} 
Amir H Alizadeh, Nikos K Nomikos, and Panos K Pouliasis. 2008. A Markov regime switching approach for hedging energy commodities. Journal of Banking \& Finance 32, 9 (2008), 1970---1983

\bibitem{43} 
Michael Bock and Roland Mestel. 2009. A regime-switching relative value arbitrage rule. In Operations research proceedings 2008. Springer, -9--14.

\bibitem{44} 
Ying Ma, Leonard MacLean, Kuan Xu, and Yonggan Zhao. 2011. A portfolio optimization model with regime-switching risk factors for sector exchange traded funds. Pac J Optim 7, 2 (2011), 281--296.

\bibitem{45} 
Timothy D. Mount, Yumei Ning, and Xiaobin Cai. 2006. Predicting price spikes in electricity markets using a regime-switching model with time-varying parameters. Energy Economics 28, 1 (2006), 62--80.

\bibitem{46} 
Glosten, L., Jagannathan, R., \& Runkle, D. (1993). On the Relation between the Expected Value and the Volatility of the Nominal Excess Return on Stocks. The Journal of Finance, 48(5), 1779--1801. 
\url{doi:10.2307/2329067}

\bibitem{47} 
Markus Haas, Stefan Mittnik, and Marc S. Paolella (2004). “A New Approach to 
Markov-Switching GARCH Models.” Journal of Financial Econometrics, 
2(4), 493--530. 
\url{doi:10.1093/jjfinec/nbh020}.

\bibitem{48} 
Klaassen F (2002). “Improving GARCH Volatility Forecasts with Regime Switching GARCH.” Empirical Economics, 27(2), 363--394. 
\url{doi:10.1007/s0018 10100100}.

\bibitem{49} 
Ardia D (2008). Financial Risk Management with Bayesian Estimation of GARCH Models: Theory and Applications, volume 612 of Lecture Notes in Economics and Mathematical Systems. Springer-Verlag, Berlin Heidelberg. 
\url{doi:10.1007/978-3-540-78657-3}.

\bibitem{50} 
Christoffersen, P. (1998). Evaluating Interval Forecasts. International Economic Review, 39(4), 841--862. \url{doi:10.2307/2527341}

\bibitem{51} 
Engle, R., \& Manganelli, S. (2004). CAViaR: Conditional Autoregressive Value at Risk by Regression Quantiles. Journal of Business \& Economic Statistics, 22(4), 367--381. Retrieved September 2, 2021, from 
\url{http://www.jstor.org/stable/1392044}

\end{thebibliography}
\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear @Mico, thanks for your help. Unfortunately, I still run into the same problem when running the code on the overleaf plateform :( You can check the edited part of my original post to verify. Is there anything else I can do to improve my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BlgKhalil - Even after your edit, the code in what's now entry #5 is garbled. Also, do remove the `\bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography{}` directives. Do also change `\begin{thebibliography}{}` to `\begin{thebibliography}{99}`. Finally, while I said the `\text` wrappers should be removed, I definitely did *not* say that the `\texttt` wrappers should be removed as well. All of the latter should really be replaced with `\url` wrappers, and the `xurl` package should be loaded immediately before `hyperref`.

Comment: Oh, one more thing: Please surround the code of the title page with `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` statements, in order to limit the scope of the suspicious-looking `\let\newpage\relax` directive to the title page itself.

Comment: Thank you so much @Mico! Your last comment is what solved the issue. I cannot thank you enough.

Comment: @BlgKhalil - You're most welcome.